# Swift: How to pass closure argument from a class method to a function in the class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have this class defined in my app to handle requests to my backend

```
class BackendService {      
    // Retrieves user chat channels
    class func getChatChannels(success:(response: Response)->(), failure: (response:Response)->()) {        
        let chatsURL = baseURL + "/chats"
        performRequestWith(success, failure: failure, url: chatsURL, parameters: nil)
    }

    func performRequestWith(success:(response: Response)->(), failure: (response: Response) -> (), url: String, parameters: String?) {
        var manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance

        let keychain = Keychain(service:"com.domain.app")
        let token = keychain.get("token")

        if let token = token {            
            manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]

            manager.request(.GET, url, parameters:nil).responseJSON { (req, res, json, err) in

                if(err != nil) {                    
                    var response = Response()
                    response.error = err
                    failure(response: response)                    
                } else {                    
                    var response = Response()

                    if let httpStatus = HTTPStatus(rawValue: res!.statusCode) {
                        response.httpStatus = httpStatus
                    }

                    response.payload = JSON(json!)
                    success(response: response)
                }
            }            
        }
    } 
}
```

I am trying to pass the callback/closure arguments that `getChatChannels` receives to `performRequestWith`. In `performRequestWith(success, failure: failure, url: chatsURL, parameters: nil)` I am getting `Extra argument 'failure' in call`

I have little experience with Swift and I am clearly doing something awfully wrong here. Some help would much appreciated.

Comment: Nop, compile-time error `Extra argument in call`. The funny thing is for some reason XCode tries to autocomplete the function as `performRequestWith(*BackendService*)`

Comment: Btw, in Swift those methods are called *"type methods"*. They are indicated with the keyword `class` for classes and `static` for structs and enums. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with your method calling code.
The issue is you are calling a instance method from a class method.

Either you should change both methods to class method, like:

```
class func getChatChannels(success:(response: Response)->(), failure: (response:Response)->())
{        
    let chatsURL = baseURL + "/chats"
    performRequestWith(success, failure: failure, url: chatsURL, parameters: nil)
}

class func performRequestWith(success:(response: Response)->(), failure: (response: Response) -> (), url: String, parameters: String?)
{
    // Your code
}
```

or Change both to instance method, like:

```
func getChatChannels(success:(response: Response)->(), failure: (response:Response)->())
{        
    let chatsURL = baseURL + "/chats"
    performRequestWith(success, failure: failure, url: chatsURL, parameters: nil)
}

func performRequestWith(success:(response: Response)->(), failure: (response: Response) -> (), url: String, parameters: String?)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Another option is create an instance of the class inside the class method and using that call the instance method.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. However I want the getChatChannels method to be a type method, publicly available and the performRequestwith: to be used only internaly only by the class. How can I make this distinguishment? Making them both type methods doesn't make so much sense to me.

Comment: @Thanos: Please read my answer one more, *Another option is create an instance of the class inside the class method and using that call the instance method.* Using this way, you keep the method as they are. Internal method, should be instance method-there is no rule like that. If you write that in .m file (no declaration in .h) then it will be a internal function, no matter if it is a class method or instance method.